# Python warnings occuring although disabled

Tags: python, warnings, disable

I have a rather large python2.7 project where due to package updates a set of warnings started to show up. For the time being, I want to disable them, to be able to fix another problem, before I can look into the warnings (I do know about the risks of ignorign warnings!).
I have one 4-line main function calling the whole rest of the project. I already added `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")` to my main programm, I added `np.warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')` to every file where numpy gets imported and I tried to use the `-W` option (all of these in various combinations).

Yet: the warnings still occur. Why is this and what can I do about it?

This is my output

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py:4: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from .tslib import iNaT, NaT, Timestamp, Timedelta, OutOfBoundsDatetime
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py:26: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import (hashtable as _hashtable,
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/common.py:6: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import algos, lib
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/util/hashing.py:7: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import hashing, tslib
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:7: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import (lib, index as libindex, tslib as libts,
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/offsets.py:21: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  import pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets as liboffsets
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.py:16: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import algos as libalgos, ops as libops
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/interval.py:32: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs.interval import (
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py:14: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import internals as libinternals
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/sparse/array.py:33: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  import pandas._libs.sparse as splib
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/window.py:36: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
```

Comment: can you show us your code? My guess is that these errors are emitted before you set the `filterwarnings()`. These look like import-time warnings.

Comment: Thanks! That was the clue. I moved the filterwarnings("ignore") line to the top of my file and not the top of my main function and now it works. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this `python -W filename.py`